# how to know the capacity of a shared drive

Tags: windows, windows-10, network-shares, sharing

I'm working on a network of Windows-10 computers. I have access to other computers' C:-drives, using the IP address, followed by "C$": in Windows Explorer, I type "\\10.10.10.1\C$", and as this C:-drive is shared, I can see the contents.

Today I'm faced with a question about low diskspace. I can easily do the investigation of the used space on that computer, using WindirStat or SequoiaView, but I don't know how to find the capacity of that drive. (When I type "\\10.10.10.1" in Windows Explorer, I don't see the C:-drive, so I can't ask its properties)

Does anybody know how to deal with this?

Comment: You can always go to the server, which handles the share drive, to determine this information.

Comment: From command prompt do a `net use z: \\10.10.10.1\c$` and then go to Windows File Explorer and on the root where you see the space as all the other drives you'll see the used and free space for this UNC path as the "Z" drive you mapped it as. Once done with it, simply right click and select disconnect. While it is mapped though, try launching a new instance of WindirStat once it exists and see if it'll see it this way. Just be sure to close the app and re-open it if it was opened before the "Z" drive mapped to the path you specify. Have a look at -> [net use](https://ss64.com/nt/net-use.html)

Answer (score 3):

As written in one of the comments we must run below command in command prompt

where z is the name of new drive which does not exist in your syst,

```
net use z: \\path of the folder
```

You can use x/y instead of z or any other characters

One you run this command, shared drive will be mapped in your system

Now simply right click and then properties, it will show you the size of it.

Answer (score 1):

When you go to \ip\c$ you can right click and do properties that will show the C drive of the system you connected too. You can also map a drive to C$ and give it a drive letter and right click it and properties. As a note the "$" is a hidden share so you will never see it from \ip